# mmap(): resetting old memory to a zero'd non-resident state

Tags: linux, macos, memory-management, posix, mmap

I'm writing a memory allocation routine, and it's currently running smoothly. I get my memory from the OS with mmap() in 4096-byte pages. When I start my memory allocator I allocate 1gig of virtual address space with mmap(), and then as allocations are made I divide it up into hunks according to the specifics of my allocation algorithm.

I feel safe allocating as much as a 1gig of memory on a whim because I know mmap() doesn't actually put pages into physical memory until I actually write to them.

Now, the program using my allocator might have a spurt where it needs a lot of memory, and in this case the OS would have to eventually put a whole 1gig worth of pages into physical RAM. The trouble is that the program might then go into a dormant period where it frees most of that 1gig and then uses only minimal amounts of memory. Yet, all I really do inside of my allocator's MyFree() function is to flip a few bits of bookkeeping data which mark the previously used gig as free, but I know this doesn't cause the OS remove those pages from physical memory.

I can't use something like munmap() to fix this problem, because the nature of the allocation algorithm is such that it requires a continuous region of memory without any holes in it. Basically I need a way to tell the OS "Listen, you can take these pages out of physical memory and clear them to 0, but please remap them on the fly when I need them again, as if they were freshly mmap()'d"

What would be the best way to go about this?

Actually, after writing this all up I just realized that I can probably do an munmap() followed immediately by a fresh mmap(). Would that be the correct way to go about? I get the sense that there's probably some more efficient way to do this.

Comment: Virtual memory automatically moves unused memory out of physical memory into swap space. You don't need to do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for `madvise(addr, length, MADV_DONTNEED)`.  From [the manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/2/madvise):

> **MADV_DONTNEED**:  Do not expect access in the near future. (For the time being, the application is finished with the given range, so the kernel can free resources associated with it.) Subsequent accesses of pages in this range will succeed, but will result either in reloading of the memory contents from the underlying mapped file (see mmap(2)) or zero-fill-on-demand pages for mappings without an underlying file.

Note especially the language about how subsequent accesses will succeed but revert to zero-fill-on-demand (for mappings without an underlying file).

Your thinking-out-loud alternative of an `munmap` followed immediately by another `mmap` will also work but risks kernel-side inefficiencies because it is no longer tracking the allocation a single contiguous region; if there are many such unmap-and-remap events the kernelside data structures might wind up being quite bloated.

By the way, with this kind of allocator it's very important that you use `MAP_NORESERVE` for the initial allocation, and then touch each page as you allocate it, and trap any resulting `SIGSEGV` and fail the allocation.  (And you'll need to document that your allocator installs a handler for `SIGSEGV`.) If you don't do this your application will not work on systems that have disabled memory overcommit.  See the [mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) manpage for more detail.

Comment: How would I revert the effect of `MADV_DONTNEED`? Just writing to it?

Comment: You can't _undo_ the effect, but a subsequent read or write to the page will _end_ the effect: the page will be allocated again and will be treated normally by the memory manager.